# AutoReadSMS NOT working after publishing app tothe playstore

Tags: android

I have tested locally autoread sms functionality using the hashkey using debug and release modes of the application. but once i published the application to the playstore when trying to read sms ..itsnot working. any helpis appreciated.

Comment: I have also loaded aab into internal testing to check the hash of signed app signature file . it created a different hashkey and autoread also worked but after publishing its not working . Am i doing something wrong??